# How to fix spacing between words in jsPDF

Tags: jspdf

Rendering PDF from HTML. The rendered html with all styles applied looks like this:

[image]
When rendered with jsPDF it looks like this:

[image]

Ignore the font weights and notice the extra space between words

```
  const pdf = new jsPDF()

  pdf.html(renderToString(letter_html), {
       callback: (doc) => {
            doc.save('letter.pdf')
       }
  })
```

Is there a fix?

Comment: To anyone else encountering this issue (as I am), it seems that this is to do with embedded fonts. jsPDF ensures that the text takes up the same amount of space as the original, but with the available fonts. Embedding the correct font seems to fix the issue.